# Why is Express taking so long between console logs on AngularJS $http.get?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, express

Using Express, Node, and Angular, I set up a HTML button on my site that runs a get request to Express which subsequently runs a function that console logs a predefined message. The first time I hit the button, the log appears instantly in my terminal. **The problem** is any time I hit it after the first time, there is a huge delay in printing the console message. Thanks in advance for any help!

**MY FILES**

analysis.server.routes.js => Express file that handles the routes for the analysis page.

```
'use strict';

module.exports = function(app) {
    // analysis routes
    app.route('/image_analysis')
        .get(function(req, res) {
            console.log('I\'ve been hit!!!');
        });
};
```

analysis.client.controller.js => AngularJS controller. When HTML button is pressed, sayHello function runs

```
'use strict';

angular.module('analysis').controller('AnalysisController', ['$scope', '$http', '$location', 'Authentication',
    function($scope, $http, $location, Authentication) {
        $scope.user = Authentication.user;
        $scope.sidebarCollapsed = false;

        // redirect to homepage if user isn't logged in
        if (!$scope.user) $location.path('/');

        $scope.sayHello = function() {
            $http.get('/image_analysis');
        };

        // highlight open chevron on mouseover

        $scope.toggleSidebar = function() {
            /* jshint ignore:start */
            $("#wrapper").toggleClass("toggled");
            /* jshint ignore:end */
            $scope.sidebarCollapsed = !$scope.sidebarCollapsed;
        };
    }
]);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it is because you are not ending the response in the route's `get` hanlder.

Try this.

```
module.exports = function(app) {
    // analysis routes
    app.route('/image_analysis')
        .get(function(req, res) {
            console.log('I\'ve been hit!!!');
            res.end();
        });
};
```

Comment: Would it be proper to put the res.end() in a promise that occurs after the console log?